# windows 7 & windows 2008 shows different html output

Tags: html, devexpress

This is a very puzzling situation. In my development machine (Windows 7 64 bit IIS 7.5), the html output is just the way I like it. However, when I deployed to server (Windows 2008 R2 64 bit IIS 7.5) the output becomes distorted.

I am using DevExpress controls.

[image: Development machine, Windows 7]

[image: Server Windows 2008 R2]

Comment: Cant see the screenshot image!

Comment: The browser make and model is likely to be more important than the OS. Are you sure all style sheets are getting loaded?

Comment: Yes, stylesheets are the same. In fact I do not use much css. I agree with you. that's why i said it's puzzling. I am not sure what to search to find the solution. I am using the same browser to access the local and server. I tried IE and Chrome, with same results.

Comment: Well, what *are* browser make and model in these examples? (The screen shots worked for me btw)

Comment: I tried IE and Chrome, with same results

Comment: I added the images again. I don't see it here, hope you guys got the correct formatting...

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the textareas?

Comment: I view source of the both output and found a lot of differences between the 2, like visibility=hidden. Maybe these breaks the UI in server, and probably these come from the devexpress controls. Something to feedback to them.

Comment: Why not show the differences in your question

Answer (score 0):

please check the **CSS Conflict**. when use other CSS with shared element name in devexpress CSS you have conflict.

**Note sulotion:** you can check and test it with **Inspect Element** tool.